# Mac high sierra ssh Invalid key length

Tags: ssh, macos-sierra

I can not make an ssh connection to my switch.
When start to connect I get this message.

"no matching cipher found. Their offer: aes128-cbc,3des-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc"

For some of the switches the following works.

ssh -oKexAlgorithms=+diffie-hellman-group1-sha1 -c aes256-cbc user@192.168.x.x
But in some switch, I get the following error.

"ssh_dispatch_run_fatal: Connection to 192.168.x.x port 22: Invalid key length"

Can somebody help me to fix this?

Comment: StackOverflow's scope is limited to questions about *writing code*. This would typically be a better fit for [SuperUser](https://superuser.com/) or [unix.se].

Answer (score 0):

You will need to regenerate the key on the switches because the key is too short for the newer ssh standards.Make sure your new key has at least 1024 bits.

Comment: that works only if the device is kind enough to support such a feature.  there are things out there like net managed pdu's that you have no option on key length

Answer (score 0):

I ran into something similar recently. It looks like the 1024 bit host key requirement is hard coded in the SSH client. I found that the version of openSSH that comes with CentOS 6.10 didn't have the 1024 bit host key requirement. In a pinch you could setup a VM on your mac. Kenny's answer is still really the correct one. The host keys should be regenerated on the device.